# How to convert the current_timestamp time to 24 hours format in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to convert the time which is timestamp with time zone means using now() or current_timestamp

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(now()::time, 'HH24:MI:SS')
```

current time it return is '06:06:17'
but it should return  '18:06:17' but it won't return this 
what might be the cause for this

Comment: That **will** return 18:06 if that is the time where you are.  Unrelated, but: you don't need the cast to time `TO_CHAR(now(), 'HH24:MI:SS')` will do just fine.

Comment: what `select now()` returns?

Comment: thanks  'a-horse-with-no-name'  i'm using the server db which is of other time zone that's why it makes that issue and your query works fine on local database

Comment: it will returns the this '2017-02-10 06:06:17.273891-05'

Answer (score 3):

The sql should be :-

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(now(), 'HH24:MI:SS')
```